# TSQL - Querying a table column to pull out popular words for a tag cloud

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, tag-cloud

Just an exploratory question to see if anyone has done this or if, in fact it is at all possible.

We all know what a tag cloud is, and usually, a tag cloud is created by someone assigning tags. Is it possible, within the current features of SQL Server to create this automatically, maybe via trigger when a table has a record added or updated, by looking at the data within a certain column and getting popular words?

It is similar to this question: [How can I get the most popular words in a table via mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173828/how-can-i-get-the-most-popular-words-in-a-table-via-mysql). But, that is MySQL not MSSQL.

Thanks in advance.
James

Comment: You'd need to use string manipulation to convert each sentance to a set of words.  If you create a table valued function, that accepts a string, and outputs a table of words, you can then use `myData CROSS APPLY myFunction(myTable.sentance)` and then use a GROUP BY to count everything up.  Exactly what rules would be needed to break a sentance into individual words, I'll leave to you or others :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a good bit on parsing delimited string into rows:
http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/08/13/converting-parsing-delimited-string-column-in-sql-to-rows/

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/parsing-csv-values-into-multiple-rows

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648

[T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor)

If you want to parse all words, you can use the space ' ' as your delimiter, Then you get a row for each word.

Next you would simply select the result set `GROUP`ing by the word and aggregating the `COUNT`

Order your results and you're there.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. What are we looking at when it comes to the performance side of things?

Comment: @sparkyfied performance will be pretty bad. IF you have multiple rows and you're parsing in each one into a temp table your cursor may take a while. Luckily you don't need to produce a tag-cloud very often.

Comment: So the best option is on a trigger when the admin adds a record or updates a row?

Comment: If you need to update the tag cloud every time there's an update... this will need to be determined by you and your design... however if you're just adding you may speed things up by appending to the same table. Personally I try to avoid triggers and explicitly call the proc but you could do it with a trigger... personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the design approach is what makes this difficult. Just because you allow users to assign tags does not mean the tags must be stored as a single delimited list of words. You can normalize the structure into something like:

```
Create Table Posts ( Id ... not null primary key )
Create Table Tags( Id ... not null primary key, Name ... not null Unique )
Create Table PostTags
    ( PostId ... not null References Posts( Id )
    , TagId ... not null References Tags( Id ) )
```

Now your question becomes trivial:

```
Select T.Id, T.Name, Count(*) As TagCount
From PostTags As PT
    Join Tags As T
        On T.Id = PT.TagId
Group By T.Id, T.Name
Order By Count(*) Desc
```

If you insist on storing tags as delimited values, then only solution is to split the values on their delimiter by writing a custom Split function and then do your count. At the bottom is an example of a Split function. With it your query would look something like (using a comma delimiter):

```
Select Tag.Value, Count(*) As TagCount
From Posts As P
    Cross Apply dbo.Split( P.Tags, ',' ) As Tag
Group By Tag.Value
Order By Count(*) Desc
```

Split Function:

```
Create Function [dbo].[Split]
(   
    @DelimitedList nvarchar(max)
    , @Delimiter nvarchar(2) = ','
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
    (
    With CorrectedList As
        (
        Select Case When Left(@DelimitedList, DataLength(@Delimiter)/2) <> @Delimiter Then @Delimiter Else '' End
            + @DelimitedList
            + Case When Right(@DelimitedList, DataLength(@Delimiter)/2) <> @Delimiter Then @Delimiter Else '' End
            As List
            , DataLength(@Delimiter)/2 As DelimiterLen
        )
        , Numbers As 
        (
        Select TOP (Coalesce(Len(@DelimitedList),1)) Row_Number() Over ( Order By c1.object_id ) As Value
        From sys.objects As c1
            Cross Join sys.columns As c2
        )
    Select CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value) + CL.DelimiterLen As Position
        , Substring (
                    CL.List
                    , CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value) + CL.DelimiterLen     
                    , Case
                        When CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value + 1)                            
                            - CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value)
                            - CL.DelimiterLen < 0 Then Len(CL.List)
                        Else CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value + 1)                            
                            - CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value)
                            - CL.DelimiterLen
                        End
                    ) As Value
    From CorrectedList As CL
        Cross Join Numbers As N
    Where N.Value < Len(CL.List)
        And Substring(CL.List, N.Value, CL.DelimiterLen) = @Delimiter

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Word or Tag clouds need two fields: a string and a value of how many times that word or string appeared in your collection. You can then pass the results into a tag cloud tool that will display the data as you require.

Not to take away from the previous answers, as they do answer the original challenge. However, I have a simpler solution using two functions (similar to @Thomas answer), one of which uses regex to "clean" the words.

The two functions are:

> dbo.fnStripChars(a, b) --use regex 'b' to cleanse a string 'a'

> dbo.fnMakeTableFromList(a, b) --convert a single field 'a' into a tabled list, delimited by 'b'

I then apply them into a single SQL statement, using the `TOP n` feature to give me the top 10 words I want to pass onto PowerBI or some other graphical tool, for actually displaying a *word or tag cloud*.

```
SELECT TOP 10 b.[words], b.[total]
FROM
 (SELECT a.[words], count(*) AS [total]
  FROM
    (SELECT upper(l.item) AS [words]
     FROM dbo.MyTableWithWords AS c
       CROSS APPLY POTS.fnMakeTableFromList([POTS].fnStripChars(c.myColumnThatHasTheWords,'[^a-zA-Z ]'),' ') AS l) AS a
  GROUP BY a.[words]) AS b
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

As you can see, the regex is `[^a-zA-Z ]`, which is to give me only alphabetical characters and `spaces`. The space is then used as a delimiter to the make table function to separate each word individually. I apply a `count(*)`, to give me the number of times that word appears, hence then I have everything I need to give me the TOP 10 results.

Note that `CROSS APPLY` is important here so I get only data with actual "words" in each record found. Otherwise it will go through every record with or without words to extract from the column I want.

**fnStripChars()**

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[fnStripChars]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000), 
    @MatchExpression VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @MatchExpression = '%' + @MatchExpression + '%'
    WHILE PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String) > 0
        SET @String = Stuff(@String, PatIndex(@MatchExpression, @String), 1, '')
    
    RETURN @String
END
```

**fnMakeTableFromList()**

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[fnMakeTableFromList](
  @List       VARCHAR(MAX),
  @Delimiter  CHAR(1))
  RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT Item = CONVERT(VARCHAR, Item)
        FROM (SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')
              FROM (SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML,'<i>' + REPLACE(@List,@Delimiter,'</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')) AS a
                CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i)) AS y
        WHERE Item IS NOT NULL);
```

I've tested this with over 400K records and it's able to come back with my results in under 60 seconds. I think that's reasonable.