# Ordering and Selecting frequently used tags

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked on stackoverflow for a solution to this however couldn't find a good answers which outlined the issues I was having; Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is to array out 15 of the most frequent tags used from all my users subjects.

**This is how I currently select the data**

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT subject FROM `users`");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

I do apologise for the code looking nothing like what I'm trying to achieve I really don't have any clue where to begin with trying to achieve this and came here for a possible solution. Now this would work fine and I'd be able to array them out and however *my problem is* the subjects contain words along with the hash tags so an example room subject would look like `hey my name is example #follow me` how would I only grab the `#follow`and once I've grabbed all the hashtags from all of the subjects to echo the most frequent 15?

Again I apologise for the code looking nothing like what I'm trying to achieve and I appreciate anyone's help. This was the [closest post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173828/how-can-i-get-the-most-popular-words-in-a-table-via-mysql) I found to solving my issue however was not useful.

**Example**

Here is three room subjects;

```
`Hello welcome to my room #awesome #wishlist`
`Hey hows everyone doing? #friday #awesome`
`Check out my #wishlist looking #awesome`
```

**This is what I'm trying to view them as**

```
[3] #awesome [2] #wishlist [1] #friday
```

Comment: I would suggest editing your question and including sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for the suggestion great idea!

Comment: @GordonLinoff are you looking to do this in the SQL query itself or in PHP?

Comment: @avip either really whatever is easiest? Not sure where to start to be honest

Comment: @Lewis ok, I've just added an answer with a sketch of it in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to parse the result set in PHP. Once you query your subject line from the database, let's say you have them in the array `$results`, then you can build a frequency distribution of words like this:

```
$freqDist = [];
foreach($results as $row)
{
        $words = explode(" ", $row);
        foreach($words as $w)
        {
                if (array_key_exists($w, $freqDist))
                        $freqDist[$w]++;
                else
                        $freqDist[$w] = 1;
        }
}
```

You can then sort in descending order and display the distribution of words like this:

```
arsort($freqDist);

foreach($freqDist as $word => $count)
{
    if (strpos($word, '#') !== FALSE)
        echo "$word: $count\n";
    else
        echo "$word: does not contain hashtag, DROPPED\n";
}
```

You could also use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to do fancier matching if you want but I've used a naive approach with `strpos()` to assume that if the word has '#' (anywhere) it's a hashtag.

Other functions of possible use to you:

- [`str_word_count()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php): Return information about words used in a string.
- [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php): Counts all the values of an array.

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was after +1 really helpful

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

What you want to achieve here is pretty complex for an SQL query and you are likely to run in to efficiency problems with parsing the subject every time you want to run this code.

The best solution is probably to have a table that associates tags with users. You can update this table every time a user changes their subject. To get the number of times a tag is used then becomes trivial with `COUNT(DISTINCT tag)`.

Comment: If I was to do this they way outlined above I would still have to distinguish the tag from the rest of text so that I could update the number of times used?

Comment: @Lewis Yes, there isn't really any way of getting around that however you do it.